# How to display a message about updates in the plugin list

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I am trying to use the hook `in_plugin_update_message` in order to display a one line message below the name of my plugin in the admin plugin list section.
However, the function called in the hook does not seem to be triggerd: no message is displayed.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

**Building the hook**

```
global $pagenow;
if ( 'plugins.php' === $pagenow )
{
    $file   = basename( __FILE__ );
    $folder = basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
    $hook = "in_plugin_update_message-{$folder}/{$file}";
    add_action( $hook, 'your_update_message_cb');
}
```

**Callback function**

```
function your_update_message_cb( $plugin_data, $r )
{
    echo 'Hello World';
    $output = 'Hello World';
    return print $output;
}
```

Should I use another hook or is there an error in my code?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

Problems with you code:

1. You don't need to check for `$pagenow`, that action will only fire in the Plugins screen.
2. The action takes two arguments, present in your callback function, but absent in the action declaration. If you had `WP_DEBUG` enabled, you'd have seen the notice.
3. An action hook [doesn't return values](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/), you do your stuff and that's all.

Working code:

```
$file   = basename( __FILE__ );
$folder = basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
$hook = "in_plugin_update_message-{$folder}/{$file}";
add_action( $hook, 'your_update_message_cb', 10, 2 ); // 10:priority, 2:arguments #

function your_update_message_cb( $plugin_data, $r )
{
    echo 'Hello World';
}
```

Of course, this hook doesn't work if the plugin is **`inactive`**.